# CSS grid generator based on percentages not pixels

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, generator

I'm looking for a fluid CSS grid generator that's based a percentage width like 100%. Everything I've found so far requires a specified pixel width or min/max pixel width.

These grid generators are all pixel based: http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a grid based on a percentage width, you don't need a generator.

Just count.

If you want a column that is half of the body, make it `width:50%;`. Quarter? `width:25%;`

I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cUaXR/) for you.

However, making a design entirely depended on percentages to leads to some problems. While a paragraph might look fine with `width:50%;` on your screen, someone with a huge monitor might see that entire paragraph on one line, which would be obnoxious to read.

I would recommend [The 1140 Grid](http://cssgrid.net/). It's based on pixels, but is also fluid, and may suit your needs. Also, by using `max-width` everything will remain easy to read for everyone.

Comment: Update: The 1140 Grid link points to a page which says (April 9, 2013): "1140px CSS Grid Retired". It seems it's not available for download anymore, too.

Answer (score 2):

Foundation has a percentage-based grid system: http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: Just to be clear I'm not particularly recommending Foundation - it's quote bloated in my opinion. But it is percentage-based.

Comment: Oh! I just found http://neat.bourbon.io, which is also percentage-based and much more awesome.